# -webkit-background-size: cover; equivalent for IE

Tags: css, html, internet-explorer

Decided to open up the site I was working on in IE and to my suprise the image that I thought was going to take up the whole page actually just stayed in the center but in chrome and firefox thats not the case. I thought that -o worked on Ie but I was wrong after some research.

Current css:

```
.intro {
  background: url('http://www.amritray.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/01/foggy-photographs21.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  -msie-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  left: 0px;
}
```

Current HTML

```
<div class='intro'>
</div>
```

Comment: What is `-msie-background-size` ? IE uses the unprefixed `background-size` since IE9

Comment: I'm currently using IE8 so I need to be able to have the image cover the entire bacground on ie7+

Comment: Simply using a prefix won't help make it work, also IE's prefix is normally `ie` not `msie`. Here is cross-browser way to do it: http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/

Comment: I thought the prefix was `-ms-`.

Comment: IE8 doesn't support it. There's a polyfil around for it.

Comment: @janaspage Indeed. I was a bit too quick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please Replace

```
-msie-background-size: cover;
```

with

```
-ms-ie-background-size: cover;
```

Please refer URL http://jsbin.com/jubeliga/1/edit?html,css,output to view changes